# Is there a defined simple process to upgrade Google Cloud Installed Software?

Tags: google-compute-engine, upgrade, google-cloud-launcher

Google Cloud installed software through Google Cloud Launcher seems not to have a simple defined update or upgrade process. New customers are offered latest versions of software (Debian 9, Apache 2.4.25, Open JDK 1.8.0 etc.) but we old ones are not being guided about how to upgrade to those new versions. We, old customers, seem condemned to have additional resources to search, evaluate, test and deploy new versions of the software deployed by Google Cloud Launcher, or stay with the old most inefficient and probably unsafe software version (Debian 7, Apache 2.2, JDK 1.7.0 etc.). But there is another option: Migrate to Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud where upgrading software is supported: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-software.html. Amazon Web Services does update the repositories: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/add-repositories.html and of course, provides a process to update the installed software. Does Google Cloud offer an upgrading process or is planning anything in that direction, or should we users low in resources plan to move to Amazon Cloud?